# How to debug Node.js app over SSH using Cloud9

Tags: node.js, ssh, cloud9-ide

I can run Node.js apps well over Cloud9/SSH and https://docs.c9.io/running_and_debugging_code.html states that Node.js apps are the only ones that can be debugged by Cloud9 right now but when I set a breakpoint in my Node.js main app and run it, it does not break on that breakpoint.

NOTE: My app is a CS app.

Comment: Hi Clearly, what do you mean by CS app?

Comment: An application built with CoffeeScript